# How to automatically load r scripts in lib subdirectories using ProjectTemplate in R?

Tags: r

I was recently asked on twitter:

[ProjectTemplate](http://projecttemplate.net/) in R appears to only import R scripts from the `lib` folder and not nested subdirectories.

How do you import R script files in the `lib` directory when using `ProjectTemplate::load.project()` if the script files are located in subdirectories?

Comment: This seems to be missing a lot of context. I guess there must be a package with the name "ProjectTemplate". Searching and reading a bit of its documentation shows that it is mentioned in https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ReproducibleResearch.html and that it does not refer to Rstudio projects. In fact it appears to duplicate some of the Rstudio facilities.

Comment: @IRTFM Thanks for comment; I have now added the link to the ProjectTemplate website to make it clearer. I received this question on Twitter and I figured that it would be a good resource to exist on the internet. If you use ProjectTemplate, then I think the question is self-contained and makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that there is no built-in option to activate recursive loading of R Scripts in the lib directory in ProjectTemplate.

The simplest option might be to use `sourceDirectory` for each nested directory. E.g., if you have subdirectory `foo`, then you could put the following line in one of your top level R scripts in the lib directory (e.g., `lib/helpers.R`)

```
R.utils::sourceDirectory("lib/foo", modifiedOnly = FALSE)
```

If you wanted something that adapted to the project, you could put something like the following in one of your top level lib script files:

```
f <- dir("lib", full.names = TRUE)
f <- f[dir.exists(f)]
if (length(f) > 0 ) { 
    sapply(f, function(X) R.utils::sourceDirectory(X, modifiedOnly = FALSE))
}
```

It would identify any subdirectories of the `lib` directory. Then source all subdirectories recursively if any exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer I have come up with, to pull specific named directories from the `lib` file in the `ProjectTemplate` architecture.

```
get.lib.dir2 <- function (name) { #write the name of the subdirectory lib file to pull
    files <- dir("lib", full.names = TRUE)
    dir <- files[dir.exists(files)]
    choices <- str_remove_all(dir, "(lib/)")
    
    args <- try(match.arg(name, choices = choices, several.ok = T), silent = T)
    
    if(berryFunctions::is.error(args)) {
        warning(paste0("No such directory exists\n", "Please change <name>"))
    } else {
        cat(paste0("You selected: ", args, " directory\n"))
    }
    
    
    dir_get <-  sapply(name, \(x) grep(x, dir, value = T))
    
    if (args %in% choices) {
        dir_get <-  sapply(name, \(x) grep(x, dir, value = T))
        sapply(dir_get, \(X) miceadds::source.all(X))
    }
}
```

It doesn't source the variable into the environment though